# Android handling touch events and pass them to children or another view to handle

Tags: android, android-canvas

I implemented a a custom FrameLayout which contains a custom canvas and another canvas for cursor. In custom canvas I want to draw lines but in cursor canvas I just want to draw a cursor, how I can properly handle the events and pass the children and another views?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom FrameLayout override `OnInterceptTouchEvent` and return `false`. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that it is impossible to handle touch events at the same time in different views. In a view you can whether receive and handle it or receive and pass it to another view. In my case since i would like to receive and handle the touch event and draw on canvasses simultaneously, there is no way to do it because one canvas should wait till the other is finished with its drawing.